Display value in static HTML Site From Google Sheets
I am new to Google Sheets and App Script.
I currently have a static HTML website that when submitted populates my Google Sheet (this is working fine).
In my App Script I'm generating a sequential reference number that populates a cell (Again, this is working fine). But what I'm wondering is, am I able to pass this reference number back to my static HTML website so I can display it to the user on the success page?
I am a complete beginner and have tried various things I have found on Google but can't seem to find the solution. I must mention that obviously, my Google Sheet won't be open or active to the user.
This is my current App Script:
const DATA_ENTRY_SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";
const TIME_STAMP_COLUMN_NAME = "Date";
const REF_COLUMN_NAME = "Ref";
const CUST_EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME = "Email Address";
const TIME_COLUMN_NAME = "Time";


var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(DATA_ENTRY_SHEET_NAME);

const doPost = (request = {}) => {
  const { postData: { contents, type } = {} } = request;
  var data = parseFormData(contents);

  appendToGoogleSheet(data);

 return ContentService.createTextOutput(contents).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
};

function parseFormData(postData) {
  var data = {};
  var parameters = postData.split('&');

  for (var i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
    var keyValue = parameters[i].split('=');

    data[keyValue[0]] = data[keyValue[0]] ? data[keyValue[0]].concat('\n', decodeURIComponent(keyValue[1])) : decodeURIComponent(keyValue[1]);
  }

  return data;
}

function appendToGoogleSheet(data) {
  if (TIME_STAMP_COLUMN_NAME !== "") {
    data[TIME_STAMP_COLUMN_NAME]=new Date();
  }

  if (sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 2).getValue() !== 'Ref') {
    var ref = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 2).getValue().replace("Port-","");
    var ref_2 = parseFloat(ref)+1

    data[REF_COLUMN_NAME]= 'Port-' + ref_2
  } else {
     data[REF_COLUMN_NAME]='Port-10000'
  }

  if (CUST_EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME !== "") {
    data[CUST_EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME]= 'test@test-net.co.uk';
  }

  if (TIME_COLUMN_NAME !== "") {
    data[TIME_COLUMN_NAME]= '10:00';
  }

  var headers = sheet.getRange(5, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var rowData = headers.map(headerFld => data[headerFld]);
  
  sheet.appendRow(rowData)
}

This is code I found and tried
App Script
function doGet(){  
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index.html").evaluate();  
}

function bb(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var value = sheet.getRange("B9").getValue();
  return value;
}

Value from S/S
Port-10003
HTML
<input type="text" name="Number" iD="reginum" size="4" value=<?=bb()?> />


I don't think you can use getActiveSheet if the spreadsheet is not physically open (by a user). Open by ID and/or name instead.

There are some ways to make it happen. I just want to confirm, that your HTML was deployed as a WebApp? Can you provide minimal code for your HTML as well just to make your question reproducible? I am quite unsure about the Static HTML in your case.

Displaying Reference value in Static HTML using Google Apps Script Web App
This sample code was being deployed in the AppScript Web app, though I am not sure if this is what you wanted, but it can also be done through this.
You can try this code:
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function saveData(inputData) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const referenceNumber = 'REF-' + new Date().getTime();
  sheet.appendRow([referenceNumber, inputData]);
  return referenceNumber;
}

Html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <style>
    #notification {
      display: none;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function submitData() {
        const inputData = document.getElementById('inputData').value;
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(referenceNumber) {
          const notification = document.getElementById('notification');
          notification.innerText = 'Success! Reference Number: ' + referenceNumber;
          notification.style.display = 'block'; // Show notification
          document.getElementById('inputData').value = ''; // Clear the input box
        }).saveData(inputData);
      }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Data Submission</h1>
  <input type="text" id="inputData" placeholder="Enter your data" required>
  <button onclick="submitData()">Submit</button>
  <div id="notification"></div>
</body>

</html>

The submitData function in HTML calls google.script.run.saveData(inputData). This triggers the saveData function in Apps Script, which creates a unique referenceNumber.
SaveData in Apps Script generates a unique referenceNumber by appending 'REF-' to the current time in milliseconds. The input data and this referenceNumber are then saved to Google Sheets.
Sample Sheet:

Sample Web App:

Also, as I understand your statement here, am I able to pass this reference number back to my static HTML website so I can display it to the user on the success page?.
Upon submitting the data through the web app, the reference number will be displayed to the user on the success page.
Here's how to Deploy the Script as a Web App:
1. Apps Script editor, click on Deploy > Test deployments > Select type > Web app.
2. Configure your deployment Setting.

Description (This is optional)
Execute as: Set to Me. This allows the script to run under your account permissions.
Who has access: Select Anyone or Anyone with the link if you want external access.

3. Click Deploy.
Reference:
Wep App
